# Recently my react-native iOS build has started launching the expo metro bundler and I'm not sure why

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Most of my PBXNativeTarget buildPhases lists now include "[Expo] Configure project" and the launch packager.command being called in my pbxproj file is in the expo module. I tried messing with the pbxproj file manually, but made the build entirely unstable.

I've tried cleaning out the pods removing all the expo component and reinstalling only what is necessary for expo camera to no avail. Even went so far as to init a new project and copy code over, still calling npx expo.

`npm list expo`

```
├─┬ expo-camera@13.4.2
│ └── expo@49.0.6 deduped
├─┬ expo-constants@14.4.2
│ └── expo@49.0.6 deduped
└─┬ expo@49.0.6
  ├─┬ expo-application@5.3.0
  │ └── expo@49.0.6 deduped
  ├─┬ expo-file-system@15.4.2
  │ └── expo@49.0.6 deduped
  ├─┬ expo-font@11.4.0
  │ └── expo@49.0.6 deduped
  └─┬ expo-keep-awake@12.3.0
    └── expo@49.0.6 deduped
```

Yields nothing unexpected from where I stand. When I had installed the expo-camera module this issue wasn't occurring, so I don't believe the modules presence on their own are at fault.

And here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "notjustphotos",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.5",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1428.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "^13.4.2",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.9",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "vector-icons": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro": "^0.77.0",
    "metro-config": "^0.77.0",
    "metro-core": "^0.77.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

At the end of the day it's not really the end of the world but it is *really* frustrating. Any pointers on where to look would be much appreciated.